# Change all prices in the html page from one currency to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that changes the currency on the page from one to another but the problem is it is not showing currency signs and not taking decimal points. check the code below.Does any one know how to use currency sign and currency in decimal like($12.45) in the code below:

```js
var prices = [
    1500,
    2000,
    342
];
var rates = {
    USD: 1, // obviously
    EUR: 0.86
}
function updatePrices(rate) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    prices.forEach((price, index) => {
        elements[index].innerHTML = price * rate
    });
}
document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function () {
    updatePrices(rates[this.value]);
}
updatePrices(rates.USD);
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
        <select id="selector">
            <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
        <label>Currency</label>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="currencies">
    <li class="price"></li>
    <li class="price"></li>
    <li class="price"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when you are updating the HTML with `innerHTML` just append the dollar sign to it `elements[index].innerHTML = '$' + price * rate`

Comment: @ Yash Karanke Do you know sir how to add pices for two plans . Like i used toggke for monthly and annually and it is showing prices for monthly plans which i write above that is 1500,
2000,
342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format the result and declare a sing for each
currency (or any other variable you need for example look at `something_at_the_end`)

```js
var prices = [
    1500,
    2000,
    342
];            
var currencies = {
    USD: {
        rate: 1,
        sign: "$",
        something_at_the_end: "test"
    }, 
    EUR: {
        rate: 0.86,
        sign: "€",
        something_at_the_end: "EURO TEST"
    }
};
function updatePrices(currency) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    prices.forEach((price, index) => {
        elements[index].innerHTML = currency.sign + parseFloat(price * currency.rate) + currency.something_at_the_end
    });
}
document.getElementById("selector").onchange = function () {
    updatePrices(currencies[this.value]);
}
updatePrices(currencies.USD);
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s1">
        <select id="selector">
            <option value="USD" selected>USD</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
        <label>Currency</label>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="currencies">
    <li class="price"></li>
    <li class="price"></li>
    <li class="price"></li>
</ul>
```

> [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) is just to be sure that the result is [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: Awesome ... Can i add something like this /month/license after the price .. i mean $29.99/month/license some thing like this

Comment: @VarunSood you can declara anything you want in the objects `currencies` and use it

Comment: @ angel.bonev One thing there is space between $ and price . Is there any way to remove it ?

Comment: Just change this `elements[index].innerHTML = currency.sign + " " + parseFloat(price * currency.rate) + currency.something_at_the_end` to `elements[index].innerHTML = currency.sign + parseFloat(price * currency.rate) + currency.something_at_the_end`

Comment: @VarunSood I've update my answer. If you want you can read about [string concatenation](https://medium.com/@endubueze00/javascript-basics-string-concatenation-with-variables-and-interpolation-deba239debbe)

Comment: sir one more thing I have two plans monthly and annually and 1500,
 2000,   342 these prices only show in monthly. Will you please let me know how to add the price in the annual section?